# Android JobIntentService - onStartCommand vs onHandleWork

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo, android-intentservice, jobintentservice

I'm currently extending from Service class for my customized service implementation. As part of Android-O migration, I want to use **JobIntentService**.

Currenlty all my logic is in service's **onStartCommand** method.

However, as per JobIntentService I should use **onHandleWork** method for my logical part.

The [official documentation for JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) says that **[onStartCommand](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))** *Processes start commands when running as a pre-O service, enqueueing them to be later dispatched in onHandleWork(Intent).*

So, my question is do I need to keep both onStartCommand & onHandleWork methods & do I need to write the same logic in both of these methods?

**OR**

Simply onHandleWork will work?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

> Currenlty all my logic is in service's onStartCommand method.

It is unclear why you have the service, then. Your service needs to fork a background thread, and that implies creating other classes (e.g., subclasses of `Thread`, `Runnable`).

> do I need to keep both onStartCommand & onHandleWork methods & do I need to write the same logic in both of these methods?

If you are using `JobIntentService`, you put everything in `onHandleWork()`. This is a direct analogue of `onHandleIntent()` in an `IntentService` — it will be called on a background thread, and if there is no more work to be done when the method returns, the service can go away.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the 
enqueueWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Class cls, int jobId,
            @NonNull Intent work)

from the JobIntentService to start the Job

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService